# DPCT migration issue with Nvidia sample application

Tags: intel-oneapi, dpc++, intel-dpct

I’m trying to migrate CUDA code to Dpc++ using Intel DPCT tool. Here are my details:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Application: BlackScholes (Finance app. Nvidia CUDA toolkit samples)

During migration, lot of warnings have been generated by the DPCT tool:

/home/administrator/NVIDIA_CUDA-11.1_Samples/4_Finance/BlackScholes/BlackScholes.cu:116:21: warning: DPCT1003:0: Migrated API does not return error code. (*, 0) is inserted. You may need to rewrite this code.
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_CallResult,   OPT_SZ));
^
/home/administrator/NVIDIA_CUDA-11.1_Samples/4_Finance/BlackScholes/BlackScholes.cu:117:21: warning: DPCT1003:1: Migrated API does not return error code. (*, 0) is inserted. You may need to rewrite this code.
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_PutResult,    OPT_SZ));
^
/home/administrator/NVIDIA_CUDA-11.1_Samples/4_Finance/BlackScholes/BlackScholes.cu:118:21: warning: DPCT1003:2: Migrated API does not return error code. (*, 0) is inserted. You may need to rewrite this code.
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_StockPrice,   OPT_SZ));
^
/home/administrator/NVIDIA_CUDA-11.1_Samples/4_Finance/BlackScholes/BlackScholes.cu:119:21: warning: DPCT1003:3: Migrated API does not return error code. (*, 0) is inserted. You may need to rewrite this code.
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_OptionStrike, OPT_SZ));

Can someone tell me how to resolve these warnings?

Steps to reproduce:

1. intercept-build make
2. dpct -p compile_commands.json

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the warnings related to cudaCheckErrors by just rewriting the code.

For Example:
"*checkCudaErrors*(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_CallResult, OPT_SZ));" can be rewritten as "cudaMalloc((void **)&d_CallResult, OPT_SZ);" i.e explicitly remove "*checkCudaErrors*" in cuda source code. Same follows with the other cudaCheckErrors warnings.

Later try migrating the code.